# Deleting the files from a SFTP server based modified time (SSH not enabled )

Tags: linux, filenames, sftp, unix-sockets

Need to delete the files from a sftp remote server based on last modified time .Files which are older then 30 days no need to keep in server .I have tried ls -lt ,but how to copy it to local machine and get modified date from there? .Then again need to use rm command to remove files based on the date I got from listing .
We don't have ssh access over the sftp server .So can't use mtime to get modified time details directly .Also most of the commands won't support over sftp.Please share you suggestions .
The script and commands need to call as part of a etl job .

Comment: You might be able to do something with Perl or Python, which have built-in libraries to communicate with an SFTP server.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using sshfs to mount the sftp server, which will allow to treat the files as local files.